# Get the qid for a value

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm using the following query to get all claims/statements for an item, like for instance for the band `Build To Spill`.

https://w.wiki/3n3H

Some of the values, like `Boise`, `indie rock`, etc. , are items by themselves. How can I display their QID if available using my query?

Comment: just add `?ps_` to the projection part, or  not? I mean, currently you'Re using the label service magic of Blazegraph to get the strings, the pattern is `"VARNAME"Label` - so you did `?ps_Label` - if you also want the URI, just select `?ps_` as well

Comment: minor comment: if you really want just the QID and not the full URI, simply using string operations: `BIND(STRAFTER(STR(?ps_), STR(wd:) ) as ?ps_Id)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks. https://w.wiki/3n65